# get size of value in a map javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, maps

I have below array object of key of Id and List of value pair. I want to get for each key what is the length of the value like

```
[
  {
    "key": "a5a5E0000003uzTQAQ",
    "value": 1
  },
  {
    "key": "a5a5E0000003uzYQAQ",
    "value": 2
  }
]
```

I am trying below code , but it is giving me undefined in the length of the value.

```js
var message = [
  {
    "key": "a5a5E0000003uzTQAQ",
    "value": [
      {
        "Name": "Features1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "a5a5E0000003uzYQAQ",
    "value": [
      {
        "Name": "AEO Analysis - Engagement"
      },
      {
        "Name": "AEO Analysis - Engagement 1",
      }
    ]
  }
]

let noOfFields = []
for (let key in message) {
                      if (message.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                          noOfFields.push({key: key, value: message[key].length });
                      }
                  }

console.log(noOfFields)
```

Comment: `key` isn't a dynamic value but just a string property. You can just `map()` over the array. `const noOfFields = message.map(({key, value}) => ({key, value: value.length}));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array.map`

```js
const message = [
  {
    "key": "a5a5E0000003uzTQAQ",
    "value": [
      {
        "Name": "Features1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "a5a5E0000003uzYQAQ",
    "value": [
      {
        "Name": "AEO Analysis - Engagement"
      },
      {
        "Name": "AEO Analysis - Engagement 1",
      }
    ]
  }
]

const noOfFields = message.map((obj) => {
  return {
    key: obj.key,
    value: obj.value.length
  }
})

console.log(noOfFields)
```

Result:

```
[
  { key: 'a5a5E0000003uzTQAQ', value: 1 },
  { key: 'a5a5E0000003uzYQAQ', value: 2 }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the length you just need this:

```js
var message = [
  {
    "key": "a5a5E0000003uzTQAQ",
    "value": [
      {
        "Name": "Features1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "a5a5E0000003uzYQAQ",
    "value": [
      {
        "Name": "AEO Analysis - Engagement"
      },
      {
        "Name": "AEO Analysis - Engagement 1",
      }
    ]
  }
]

let noOfFields = []
for (let key in message) {
                      if (message.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                          noOfFields.push({key: key, value: message[key].value.length });
                      }
                  }

console.log(noOfFields)
```

It's a little misleading to call the length of the value 'value' though.